# Access Array inside an object (json)

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I have this json file and I want to access the array that is inside this object:

```
best-sellers": [
    {
      "title": "Chuteira Nike HyperVenomX Proximo II Society",
      "price": 499.90,
      "installments": {
        "number": 10,
        "value": 49.90
      },
      "high-top": true,
      "category": "society",
      "image": ""
    },
    {
      "title": "Chuteira Nike HyperVenom Phantom III Cano Alto Campo",
      "price": 899.90,
      "installments": {
        "number": 10,
        "value": 89.90
      },
      "high-top": true,
      "category": "campo",
      "image": ""
    }
}
]
```

This is the code on my component:

```
   ngOnInit(): void {
      this.service
      .lista()
      .subscribe(chuteiras =>{
        this.chuteiras = chuteiras;
      })
  }
```

and my template looks like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let chuteira of chuteiras.best-sellers">
```

But angular is not reconigzing it the `best-sellers", here's the error that I'm getting:

> Cannot read property 'best' of undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use bracket notation,

```
<div *ngFor="let chuteira of chuteiras["best-sellers"]">
```

Comment: now I'm getting this "Cannot read property 'best-sellers' of undefined"

Comment: nevermind, I use the bracket notation on the `ngOnInit` instead and it worked, thanks

Answer (score 0):

well,that's one way of doing it but angular 6 came with a simple solution. when i was faced with this problem i myself resolved to this solution but it didn't work for me so after searching and making my own touches i ended up with this solution.

1.create the function to receive the JSON data in my case i used a web API

`getTrending() {
    return this.http.get(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/trending/all/day?api_key=${this.api_key}`);
  }`

2.call the function in my case i used a service, so after import it to my component i simply added this
      `showPopular(): void {
         this.api.getTrending().subscribe((data:  Array<object>) => {
          this.list  =  data['results'];
          console.log(this.list);
       });
      }`

as you can see the data variable only accessed the information i required.